# How to loop through all webs and sub webs of a SharePoint Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to loop through all webs and subs-webs of those webs under a web.

My Parent web

http://EXAMPLE.com/parentweb (This is a sub site not a root web)

sub webs
http://example.com/parentweb/subweb ( This is one of the sub web which may or may not have sub webs)

The only thing i tried is go to the site collection and loop throug all webs which is much longer process because i know the only sub site that needs to be checked. my site collection has multiple sub sites. i don't want to loop through all subs sites.

This code works but it takes so much of time and it loops through all subsites which don't need to be checked

```
     using(SPSite site = new SPSite(“http://myserver/mysitecol”) 
           { 
               foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs) 
               {
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.Webs` property of an `SPWeb` object to access its **direct** child subsites.

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myserver/mysitecol") 
{ 
    using(SPWeb parentweb = site.OpenWeb("subweb/subweb") 
    {
        foreach(SPWeb web in parentweb.Webs)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

To access **all** (including indirect) descendant child sites below a Web, you could access that `.Webs` property recursively on each direct descendent, but it would be more straightforward to start with the `.AllWebs` property of the `SPSite` site collection object.

The `.WebsInfo` property of the SPWebCollection returned by `.AllWebs` gives you a `List<>` of lightweight `SPWebInfo` objects. You can use this lightweight collection to get a filtered list of the Webs you care about without having to instantiate and dispose of any of the other SPWebs in the collection.

```
string webUrl = "/mysitecol/subweb/subweb";
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myserver/mysitecol") 
{ 
    List<SPWebInfo> websInfo = site.AllWebs.WebsInfo.FindAll(
        delegate(WebsInfo webInfo)
        {
            // filter to get us only the webs that start with our desired URL
            return webInfo.ServerRelativeUrl.StartsWith(webUrl);
        }
    );
    foreach(SPWebInfo webInfo in websInfo)
    {
         using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webInfo.Id))
         {

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will give the immediate webs only not the sub webs of the immediate children webs

Comment: Gotcha. Well, you could recursively access the `.Webs` property of each child web as you loop through, but I suspect it'll be faster to use the `AllWebs.WebsInfo` property on the `SPSite` object. I'll update my answer.