# sharepoint subsite of subsite

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

i have a requirement to loop all document libraries from sharpeoint server, however i failed at subsite of the subsite

first of all i use method below to get my SiteCollections

```
internal List<string> GetAllSite()
    {
        List<string> siteCollection = new List<string>();
        try
        {

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                SPServiceCollection services = SPFarm.Local.Services;
                foreach (SPService curService in services)
                {
                    if (curService is SPWebService)
                    {
                        SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)curService;


                        foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications)
                        {
                            foreach (SPSite sc in webApp.Sites)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    siteCollection.Add(sc.Url);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Do something with site at: {0}", sc.Url);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: {0}\r\n{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return siteCollection;
    }
```

after that i use the return sitecollection url to loop for subsite as below code

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteCollectionUrl))
                {

                    foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                    {
                          //i get the subsite url from here

                    }

                }
```

right now here is my problem, as i mentioned earlier, i wanted to get subsite of the subsite, so i pass my subsite url to SPSite, however it will only loop SiteCollections instead of my subsites

foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs) <-- i means here, over here will only loop my sitecollection item alhought i already pass my subsite url as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want **direct** descendent subsites of a given site, you should use the [`SPWeb.Webs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webs.aspx) property instead of the `SPSite.AllWebs` property.

> Gets a website collection object that represents all websites immediately beneath the website, excluding children of those websites.

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SiteCollectionUrl))
{
    using(SPWeb parentSite = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
    {
       foreach (SPWeb subsite in parentSite.Webs)
       {
            // do something with subsite here
            subsite.Dispose();
       }
    }
    siteCollection.Dispose();
}
```

If you also need to get all the subsites of those subsites until all descendants (both direct and indirect) are accounted for, you should use recursion within the loop.

Note that instantiating and disposing of SPWeb objects for each subsite can be performance burden.

If you don't need to access the full properties of each subsite, you're better off using the site collection's `AllWebs` property to get a reference to an `SPWebCollection` object. You can then use the `WebsInfo` property of that `SPWebCollection` to get a `List<>` of lightweight SPWebInfo objects, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287458/how-to-loop-through-all-webs-and-sub-webs-of-a-sharepoint-web/36287810#36287810).